# Read project.json version number at runtime

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, project.json

How can one read the `project.json` version number at runtime?  I.e. the "1.0.0-1234" in the config below:

```
{
  "title": "MyProject.Api",
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-1234",
  "dependencies": {
     ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Comment: `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>().InformationalVersion` will get your the full `version` value.

Comment: @haim770 This doesn't work in dotnet 1.0.0. Gives you "File version" which `dotnet publish --version-suffix xxx` doesn't change. What it actually does change is "Product version" but I have no idea how to get this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can read it using the static helper:

```
Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions.PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationVersion
```

Comment: I only get back "1.0.0.0" for the above example. Any idea why this would be the case?

Comment: @davenewza check if you have version twice in my project.json

Comment: `ApplicationVersion` does not include any of the version after the `-`. so your version number is being truncated to `1.0.0`, which is equivalent to `1.0.0.0`. If you update your version to e.g. `1.0.0.1234`, or `1.1.0-1234`, you will see the version number as `1.0.0.1234` or `1.1.0.0` respectively

Comment: This doesn't work in dotnet 1.0.0. Gives you "File version" which `dotnet publish --version-suffix xxx` doesn't change. What it actually does change is "Product version" but I have no idea how to get this one.

Comment: The assembly version has historically ben <int>.<int>.<int>.<int>  (Major.Minor.Hotfix.Revision)  and VS projects have always supported 1.0.0.* and the wildcard was replaced with an integer.  Why asp.net core version decided to support a string and only after a hypen is crazy.  Under the covers, it appears that the value is being cast to an integer and that is why the hyphen and everything after is lost.

Comment: "Why asp.net core version decided to support a string" - to conform with the SemVer standards. http://semver.org/